# Base 64 decode returning NULL in C

Tags: c, base64, decode, glib

I have a base 64 encoded string that I want to decode. 
It looks like this:

```
VGhpcyBpcyBhIGZpbGUgdGhhdCBJIHdhbnQgdG8gZGVjb2Rl
```

when I do..

```
gsize *out_len;
unsigned const char *decoded;
decoded = g_base_64_decode(myString, out_len);
```

and print out my decoded string, I get NULL also,  i get the assertion:
'out_len != NULL' failed from Glib

Why is this happening? How can I decode my string properly with this function? https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Base64-Encoding.html#g-base64-decode-step

Comment: Have you allocated memory for `out_len`?

Comment: `out_len` points nowhere. Replace `gsize *out_len;` with `gsize out_len;` and `g_base_64_decode(myString, out_len);` with `g_base_64_decode(myString, &out_len);`

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: Post it an an answer!

Comment: This works thanks so much. post it and I will accept answer. stupid mistake on my part..haven't used C in a while :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `out_len` parameter is an *output* parameter. This means that you typically create an `out_len` variable of type `gsize` on the stack like this:

```
gsize out_len;
```

and then you call the function passing a *pointer* to the aforementioned variable (i.e. you pass the *address of* it: `&out_len`), e.g.:

```
decoded = g_base_64_decode(myString, &out_len);
```